# Niceness of the projection of a closed subscheme of affine space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and suppose $C\subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n+m}_k$ is a closed subscheme. What can we say about the image under the projection $\pi: \mathbb{A}^{n+m}_k\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^n_k$? We have the very general result from Chevalley's Theorem that $\pi(C)$ is a constructible set. Can we say more? For instance does it have a natural scheme structure?

$\pi(C)$ is not necessarily closed, for instance when $C=(xy-1)\subseteq\mathbb{A}^2_k$. However in this case we do have that $\pi(C)$ is locally closed rather than being a finite union of locally closed subsets. Does this hold in general? The examples I can think of where the image of a nice subscheme is properly a constructible subset don't involve a morphism as nice as the projection from an affine space.

Note that it doesn't seem that the image under $\pi$ of a locally closed set is locally closed. For instance take the standard "constructible but not locally closed set" example in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ which is the complement of the $x$-axis, but including the origin (i.e. $\left(\mathbb{A}^2_k\setminus (y)\right) \cup (x,y)$). This is the image under $\pi:\mathbb{A}^3_k\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^2_k$ of $(z)\setminus (z,y)$ union the line $(t,t,1)$ (i.e. $((x-y),(z-1))$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $\pi(C)$ is not always locally closed.

For instance, take $C=V(x-yz)$ in $\mathbb{A}_k^3$, and $\pi:\mathbb{A}_k^3\rightarrow \mathbb{A}_k^2$ is defined by $\pi(x,y,z)=(x,y)$, then $\pi(C)=\left(\mathbb{A}_k^2\setminus (y)\right)\cup(x,y)$, which is exactly the standard "constructible but not locally closed set" in your question.

Comment: Ah yes of course. I'm not sure why I wasn't able to construct something along these lines--thanks!